# Weak Link My Own Objective-C Class

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to weak link my own objective-c classes?

I have seen that I can weak link a function or a variable…

```
extern int MyFunction() __attribute__((weak_import));
extern int MyVariable __attribute__((weak_import));
```

I would like to have something like this…

```
if ([MyUploadManager class]) {
  self.uploadButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

… and be able to compile even if UploadManager.m is not included in the project.

Comment: Curious, what are you trying to do what requires the ability to do this?

Comment: What does `if([Classname class])` do? When would it be false?

Comment: @stevesliva Cocoa and CocoaTouch has the ability to check for the absence of new APIs on older versions of the operating system. Checking for the truth value of `[SystemClass class]` is how you do it. The question is asking how to do it for one's own classes, though I would have to imagine that this would only really apply if you're packing your classes in a framework. For more information, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html

Comment: @BergQuester Just curious: I understand where you are coming from as far as `[System class]` is concerned, but let say class `B` were in framework `A`, and if we didn't link to this framework (i.e. no `import A_A/A.h`, the above wouldn't even compile in the first place, right? Other words, it would be redundant to check `[MyUploadManager class]` if we didn't `import` the framework in the first place, right? Thanks. I have a feeling that the OP comes from the Java world.

Comment: Weak import may not help you. Weak import allows the class to be absent at runtime, but still requires the class to be present at build time.

Comment: @GregParker Why would there be a need to make something available only at build time and not runtime? The other way around I would understand. Funny analogy: if I sent a package at post office and declare that I had "chocolate and candies" (build-time) but at the destination post office the postman only saw candies, he would still know there is also chocolate there (runtime). I think it would be more powerful if we could "declare" that we only have candies (build time), but at the destination post office (runtime) a chocolate bar could also surface. I hope you could understand what I mean.

Comment: It's for deployment on old OS versions. For example, the OS X 10.9 SDK defines some new class at build time, but when you run on OS X 10.8 that class does not exist.

Comment: @Unheilig Yes, it's like What Greg Parker said. You can compile against the 10.9 SDK frameworks and run on 10.8. If you don't link against a framework that has your class or method, it won't build, it must be present at build time. However, you can check for the class or method at run time and work around it's absence on 10.8.

Comment: For example, `NSAppearance` is new in 10.9. In order to refer to `NSAppearance` in your code you *must* link against the 10.9 sdk so that it is present, building against 10.8 will cause the build to fail. However, you can do `if ([NSAppearance class])` in your code to check at run time for the class and do something different if it does not exist, as would be the cade if your app was running on 10.8.

Comment: You can do the same thing with a new method. For example, `occlusionState` is a new method on `NSApplication` in 10.9. You can check, at run time, if you're running on an OS that supports the method by writing `if ([NSApplication respondsToSelector:@selector(occlusionState)])`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To weak link a class e.g. `MyUploadManager` in your own executable:

1. **To keep the linker happy, add this to `Other Linker Flags` in the project:**

   ```
   -Wl,-U,_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyUploadManager
   ```

   This allows the class symbol to be undefined even if it is not built into your executable. It will be considered for dynamic lookup instead, effectively the same as a dynamic library symbol.
2. **To keep the runtime happy, add this to your class header:**

   ```
   __attribute__((weak_import)) @interface MyUploadManager
   ```

   When the dynamic linker runs, it substitutes a `nil` for the class symbol rather than crashing.

Now you can run this without either linker or runtime errors:

```
if ([MyUploadManager class]) {
  self.uploadButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

Note: As of Xcode 7, the `-U` linker options conflicts with BitCode, so you may not be able to use this technique for future projects.

Comment: is there a way to do this when I do not have access to the class so I can't add `__attribute__((weak_import))`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `NSClassFromString` function:

```
Class MyUploadManager = NSClassFromString(@"MyUploadManager");
if (MyUploadManager) {
    self.uploadButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

`NSClassFromString` returns `nil` if the class cannot be found.

Comment: Sorry, this is what I am trying to avoid. The code to use this class ends up really ugly.

Comment: @Onato: What's ugly? Other than the call to get the class from `NSClassFromString`, using the class is the same as if it was statically linked. At any rate, if you're conditionally using a class, there's going to be *some* ugliness.

Comment: My example was very basic. As thing get more complex you have to use respondsToSelector and performSelector to call methods safely. In my case I can avoid the ugliness as my weak linking code is also in a framework.

Comment: @Onato: How does it being in a framework change anything? You still won't know whether the classes (or methods) are available or not unless you check.

Comment: What was implicit but not obvious in my question was that I wanted to use the NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE syntax. http://stackoverflow.com/a/23949666/215748

Answer (score 1):

To weak link a class it can be included in a framework. The compiler can be told to weak link all symbols in a framework using the `Other Linker Flag` build setting.

```
-weak_framework <framework_name>
```

This enables MyModule.framework to weak link against Uploader.framework whilst it is being built. If someone using MyModule.framework does not links against Uploader.framework then, in the example above, the button will not be displayed.

[Frameworks and Weak Linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html)